# How a discarded value can be used later in the program

Tags: c, expression

About the expression statement(an example)

```
i = 1;
```

it is said that after assigning `1` to `i` ***the value of entire expression is being discarded***. If the value is discarded then how this can be used later in the program,for example

```
printf("%d",i);
```

?
I know this is very basic question but I am really confused with *discarded*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important point is the `i = 1` has two properties.

1. It changes the value stored in the variable `i` to be 1
2. It is an expression and has a value (which is also 1);

That second part is interesting is a case like

```
if ( (i=1) == 2 ) {  // ...
```

or

```
y = 3 + (i = 1); // assign 4 to y
```

The line

> the value of entire expression is being discarded.

refers to the *value of the expression* (my #2), but does not affect assignment to variable `i` (my #1).

Comment: Now everything is clear. And reason for accepting it is #2(I missed that point).

Comment: In other words #2 can be said that **an assignment statement returns a value** and hence value return by i = 1; is discarded in this case(as it is not being stored or used after return)

Answer (score 6):

The value of the expression is indeed discarded, but this expression has a *side effect* - it changes the value of `i`. So next time you will access this variable, you will read the new value, which is 1.

The term "discarded" is more helpful when you do things like `foo(5);` or even simply `"hello";`. Since the expression `"hello"` does not have any side effect, and its value is dicarded, it is does absolutely nothing. When a compiler encounters it, as a stand alone statement:

```
"hello";
```

It may simply ignore it altogether, as if it does not exist at all. This is what happens when you call functions, or use operators:

```
4+5;
sin(2.6);
```

These expressions, too, have no side effect, and their values are ignored. When you do something like

```
printf("hello");
```

This is an expression, too. Its value is the total number of characters written. This value is ignored. But the expression must not be comletely ignored, since it has an important side effect: it prints these characters to the standard output.

So let's build a function instead of using the assignment operator (since C has no references, we'll use pointers):

```
int assign_int(int* var, int value) {
    *var = value;
    return *var;
}
```

now, back to your example, you do something like:

```
assign_int(&i, 1);
```

the value returned from `assign_int` is *discarded*. Just like in the `printf()` case. But since the function `assign_int` has a side effect (changing the value of i), it is not ignored by the compiler.

Comment: I think, I misunderstood the term *value of expression* with *value of `i`*. This is clear now. Thanks for your answer(+1).